# Installing Homebrew on El-capitan

Tags: curl, homebrew, osx-elcapitan

**When running:**

ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"

**I get the following error:**

curl: (1) Protocol "https" not supported or disabled in libcurl

- From doing research online I believe this has to do with privilege issues concerning the new weaker status of sudo user with el capitan.
- I have looked at just about every post I can find, including those that tell me to revert my sudo privileges back by using terminal commands in recovery mode on startup. However, so far all attempts were in vein.
- Im pretty sure there are no syntax errors in the command I'm running -(has double quotes instead of single, and no spaces where there shouldn't be any)

Im trying to get a bunch of studying done, and this is a real road block. Kind of hoping for a christmas miracle : )

Thank you for reading,
Dima

Comment: what is the output of `which -a curl` ?

Comment: /usr/local/bin/curl
/usr/bin/curl

!!!!!!

Theres 2! does this mean 1 supports https and one does not, and im using the one that doens't?

Comment: yes, probably. you can substitute `curl` with `/usr/bin/curl` in your command